# How to setup aws codepipeline with aws code commit + aws code build + elastic beanstalk ? without jenkins , teamcity or any other 3rd party tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

How can I setup aws codepipeline with aws code commit + aws code build + elastic beanstalk without using  jenkins, teamcity or any other 3rd party  tool?

Comment: What language is your source code in and what Elastic Beanstalk platform are you deploying to?

Answer (score 4):

If you take parts of two solutions I put together, you should be able to come up with a comprehensive solution for Elastic Beanstalk, CodePipeline, CodeCommit, and CodeBuild.

I wrote a post on using CodeCommit and CodePipeline with Elastic Beanstalk here: [Create a Pipeline for Elastic Beanstalk in CodePipeline using CloudFormation and CodeCommit](https://stelligent.com/2016/05/06/create-a-pipeline-for-elastic-beanstalk-in-codepipeline-using-cloudformation-and-codecommit/). In it, I'm using the example Node.js app from AWS. The associated launch stack and code is [here](https://github.com/stelligent/cloudformation_templates#elastic-beanstalk-codepipeline-lab).

I wrote about CodeBuild, CodePipeline, CodeCommit, and CodeDeploy integration at [Deploy to Production using AWS CodeBuild and the AWS Developer Tools Suite](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/deploy-to-production-using-aws-codebuild-and-the-aws-developer-tools-suite/). The code for the post is described at [CodeBuild and AWS Developer Tools Suite Lab](https://github.com/stelligent/cloudformation_templates#codebuild-and-aws-developer-tools-suitelab).

Depending on which programming language you're using to configure and deploy your application, you'll use a different [CodeBuild curated environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref.html#build-env-ref-available). To see a list of CodeBuild examples, go to [CodeBuild samples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/samples.html). There's a specific one for Elastic Beanstalk for Java [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-elastic-beanstalk.html).

Ultimately, you'll need to use CodeBuild to generate the ZIP file that Elastic Beanstalk uses. You orchestrate this CodeBuild action in CodePipeline and use the `OutputArtifacts` generated in your CodeBuild stage/action as an `InputArtifacts` to your ElasticBeastalk deploy action. As you see from the examples, everything can be defined in AWS CloudFormation. Hope this helps.